# «Меньше(,) чем за полминуты» — в конкретном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сравнительный-оборот

*Всего неделю назад,*(1) *до поездки в Киев,*(2) *Рубинчик легко и **меньше,***(3) ***чем за полминуты,***(4) *проходил весь длиннющий редакционный коридор — от кафе-столовой в северном крыле здания до кабинета главного редактора в его южной стороне.*
Э. Тополь. Русская дива

Такая пунктуация в предложении была в печатном варианте. В интернет-книгах запятые **(1)** и **(2)** отсутствуют, а **(3)** и **(4)** — есть (можно посмотреть [здесь](http://qlgcokem.atspace.com/part20_0.html) и [здесь](https://files.litmir.me/br/?b=90562&p=45)).
При чтении я споткнулась на обособлении **меньше, чем за полминуты**: посчитала, что оно ошибочно. Проверила в "Гугле" — и удивилась.
Я не права? Подскажите, а как бы вы расставили запятые?

Answer (score 4):

Я бы так поставила запятые:

Всего неделю назад, **до поездки в Киев,** Рубинчик **легко и меньше чем за полминуты** проходил весь длиннющий редакционный коридор — от кафе-столовой в северном крыле здания до кабинета главного редактора в его южной стороне.

1) Обособляется обстоятельство  времени с **уточняющим значением**.

2) Оборот ***меньше чем за полминуты***  имеет количественное значение, запятая перед ЧЕМ не ставится, о чем говорится в Справочнике по пунктуации.

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?id=58_415&layout=item